# How many particles do you need in a system before it can store information?

Tags: quantum-information, information

I have read that a single subatomic particle or a single atomic nucleus cannot store information, but evidently as you add more particles you will reach a point where it is possible to store information. What is this point?

Comment: Just to be clear, when you say "store information," it sounds as if you are talking about a _system_  that has two or more _stable states_, and some reliable means to probe the system to find out which state it is in, and some reliable means to intentionally put the system into a chosen state.  Is that right?

Comment: That sounds correct, yes. I don't know much about information theory.

Answer (score 2):

What you read is trivially incorrect.  For an easy counter example, consider encoding a binary bit using either C-12 (with 6 neutrons) for a 0 or C-14 (with 8 neutrons) as a 1.  That proves that you can store information in a single atomic nucleus.

The real limitation is really practical.  As you get smaller, the models you have to use are less and less forgiving.  There's really no way to *perfectly* store a bit of information, because entropy is always winning.  Even if it takes a trillion years, you will eventually lose that information.  However, we are typically interested in storing information for human-scale time periods with human-scale reliability.  For example, you might be interested in storing a bit for 6 minutes with a 99% probability that the bit is still there at the end of the 6 minutes.

As another practical example, it can become hard to read the information out of a subatomic particle.  At that size, quantum effects start to really become significant.  You can get into situations where there is no way to read the data without modifying the state of the subatomic particle.  If I have a scratch on my CD, I can re-read that sector in hopes that I can resolve that data on the next pass (or perhaps use statistics on it).  With subatomic particles, in many cases the act of reading the data changes the state of the particle, so that you won't get a second chance.

Some systems rely on this.  The next generation of "neural network" chips operate on structures so small and so low-energy that sometimes bits get flipped.  Instead of depending on the sacrosanct reliability and availability of bits, the algorithms are designed to be resilient in the face of such failures.  In exchange for this unreliability, these chips are *far* more energy efficient than their more traditional counterparts.

Comment: A good discussion of the topic, but the problems you describe are actually familiar to "classical" computing. Cosmic rays and other environmental variables have vexed computer hardware since it's invention. CDs are not reliable because of the ability to make multiple passes, it is because they (and every other shred of a classical computer) are permeated with layer on layer of redundancy and error-correction logic. It is being seen in quantum computing already that there is a need for error correction logic implemented efficiently in terms of quantum principles.

Comment: "For an easy counter example, consider encoding a binary bit using either C-12 (with 6 neutrons) for a 0 or C-14 (with 8 neutrons) as a 1. That proves that you can store information in a single atomic nucleus."

This doesn't seem like storing information in a nucleus to me, as you are using two different nuclei. It's like saying quarks can store information because you could use an up quark and a down quark to represent 1 and 0.

"sometimes bits get flipped"

Would this be because of something like quantum tunneling?

Comment: @DannyH, the point he was making was that you can (in principle) subject the nucleus to a (write) process that gives it however many neutrons you want it to have, and it can then be subject to another (read) process later that evaluates how many neutrons it has. Therefore, "information" as we know it can be stored. Quantum tunnelling is another topic altogether.

Comment: @steve I suppose, but adding a neutron to the nucleus makes it a new nucleus. If you add 2 neutrons to a c-12 atom, it's not as if that nucleus is storing information, it just becomes a different nucleus.

Comment: @Steve The reason the issues are "classical" is because the actual issue is the concept of "storing information," which had already gotten nuanced long before we got to the non-classical realm.  No need to complicate matters with quantum mechanics when they're already unsettled by classical mechanics =)

Comment: @DannyH What do you define as a "different" thing?  One can easily show that one *must* have two different things to store a bit of information.  Whether those are 2 levels of voltages, or charges, or atomic masses, you have to be able to have two different "things" which can be examined to determine if a 1 or a 0 was written.

Comment: @DannyH, sounds like the "grandfather's axe" argument. If you replace all the parts of something, but all current parts were once in relation to the original parts (through a continuous chain of non-simultaneous replacements), is it still the same object - your grandfather's axe? But for the present purpose we don't need to decide the question - the point is, whether it be the same nucleus or not, the nucleus you have is in a definite state (and any other nucleus, if it exists, has either been destroyed in the process of storage, or cast out of the scope of the storage area).

Comment: @CortAmmon, 3 things seems to be the minimum (with 2 available states for each), since you need a reference to compare the "information" against - otherwise you cannot tell that it has changed or what it says. That's used to good effect in XOR error detection, for example. In fact, the more I think about this the more "things" seem to be required, and I'm wading out of my depth!

Comment: @cort ammon I understand that, but in the case of a nucleus I would define it as "x number of protons and y number of neutrons". Any changes to x and y make it a different nucleus, but any other changes (if they are possible) leave it as the original nucleus. My question in regards to whether nuclei can store information basically boils down to "can you alter a nucleus without changing its number of protons and neutrons?"

Comment: @DannyH So if I take that logic one step further, RAM does not store information because it adds electrons, and if "x protons + y neutrons" defines an atom, then it seems reasonable that "x protons + y neutrons + z electrons" defines an atom, does it not?

Comment: As for actually storing data in the precise way you want to, [it has been done](http://blog.thesietch.org/2008/10/23/storing-information-at-the-nucleous-of-an-atom/) as well.

Comment: Fundamentally, the rule is simple: If you can have two *reasonably* stable states for an object, can cause those states to occur, and measure those states, you can store a bit.  So really, the only limit to whether you can store information in a nucleus is whether your preferred definition of "the same nucleus" admits two such states or not.  And, it turns out that's far more dependent on definitions than it is on physics.

Comment: @CortAmmon I think this links to Steves idea of the grandfather's axe above. The system which I call RAM is a bunch of circuits with variable electron numbers, this variable amount of electrons is how it stores information. If you were to change the amount of circuits it has, then I would not consider it the same RAM. In the nucleus example adding protons/neutrons is analogous to increasing the amount of circuits in some RAM.

Comment: @DannyH If you choose to define a nucleus in such a way, then you will come to the conclusion that it is exactly as difficult to store information in a nucleus as it is to add circuits to RAM.  Of course, the amazing researchers at IBM who are constantly pushing the limits of storage capacities use a different definition, but that's the fun thing about definitions -- we don't all have to use the same one... we just get different results.

Comment: @CortAmmon What other definitions for a nucleus are there than "x + y"?

Comment: @DannyH "The bundle of protons and neutrons stored in a sufficiently stable state such that the only thing that can add neutrons to it is my writing-mechanism."  The difference between this and your definition is really a philosophical one more than a physics based one.  Mine permits state changes while retaining identity while yours explicitly forbids state changes.  Thus, mine can change state to store a bit while yours cannot.  Identity is a *really* tricky concept, much less identity at a subatomic level.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72891/discussion-between-cort-ammon-and-dannyh).